Connecting to Redshift server in SAS
The data management people in my company (who are not SAS users) have sent me information to connect to one of our Redshift servers:
User ID: user
Password: pwd
Database Server: svr123
Database Port: 1234
Database: db123
Schema: data_schema_123
My SAS libname statement is as follows:
libname newlib redshift 
user="user" 
password="pwd" 
READBUFF=10000 SUB_CHAR=QUESTIONMARK 
schema="data_schema_123"
database="db123"
server="svr123"
port=1234;

I'm seeing the following error message after executing:
ERROR: CLI error trying to establish connection: [DataDirect][ODBC lib] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.

Is there anything obviously wrong with my syntax or is this more of an IT issue?

Although this is similar to another post, there are a few places to start.
Based on the Error "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" I think your IT needs to configure the ODBC ini file.
Here is a link: SAS ODBC Configs and AWS Redshift starts on page 39.
Here is a reference from sas forums that provided similar assistance:
sas forums

Thank you, this is helpful! We eventually reached the same conclusion.
